# Which username use PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

I have an Ubuntu server 14.10 with Apache, PHP, MySQL and VSFTPD.
I have a function that create some folders (Music, Videos, Documents) on /var/www/html/users/%username%/.
The problem is that, if the folder  /var/www/html/users/ have 700 permisions, the function don't create the folders, but if /var/www/html/users/ have 707 permisions, PHP can create the folders but it's so insecure... someone can read all documents from all users.

Which Unix user use PHP to create folders?

Or... exists any form to do it more secure? With MySQL + FTP or something?

Thanks all.

Comment: Try out 755 it is used for directories in Cpanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php uses the "apache" user to create

Comment: Okay! Then I'll do chown for apache. Thanks

Comment: Most of the time files are made by the user that is logged in (if you upload a file or something via ftp/sftp with filezilla) if you upload via a system like wordpress or so then it will probably be apache